# C++ equivalent to Java import and other questions

Tags: java, c++, c, import, include

For example, in Java we would have something like this:

```
import stack; // user made, which is what I want
import java.util.Scanner; // Java
package example;
public class Example{
   Stack p = new Stack();
}
```

I'm studying C++ and I once coded in C as well.But I'm mostly a Java programmer. In C I used #include "example.h" but once I searched on the internet, it only shows results for C/C++, and they say to use #include as well. But I don't get it. Will C++ have header files as well???

Also, if so, how do I check if the header file wasn't already included? Also, there is a Java documentation that Oracle gives you. Where do I check the official C++ reference to check the libraries?

Comment: Yes c++ uses header files as well.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/

Comment: Including header files is not equivalent to using `import` in Java.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answers. Thanks to you guys' comments.

To check if it wasn't defined use #ifndef as you would in C.

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
```

And yes C++ uses header files as well and it works just like C.

And the reference is at en.cppreference.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes C++ has header files as well, in fact they are a rather large part of the language. 
You include things as you would in C.
For example it's common to see

```
#include <stdio.h>
// or
#include <string>
```

In the code